# How to Validate Text box in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do the validation to four text box using  JQuery

Coding i have done

```
<table align="center" id="tbl-employee">
<tr>
<td>
<label>Insert Employee Details</label>
</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="lbl-name">Name</label>
</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="txt-name" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="lbl-salary">Salary</label>
</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="txt-salary" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="lbl-deptid">DeptId</label>
</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><select id="ddl-deptid">
<option value="0">-SelectOne-</option>
<option value="1">SoftWare</option>
<option value="2">CA</option>
<option value="3">Professor</option>
 </select>            
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="button" id="btn-insert" value="Insert" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

JavaScript code

```
  $(function () {
  $("#btn-insert").click(function () {
        $("#tbl-employee").validate({
            rules: {
                Name: { required: true, minlenth: 50 },
                Salary:{required:true,minlength:9},
                DeptId:"required"

            },
            message: {
                Name:{required:"Please Enter Name",minlength:"Your Name must lessthan 50 characters" }
            },
            submit Handler: function (table) {
                table.submit();

            }
        });

    })
})
```

Will anyone check my program,If i am not giving any text to the input text box ,while submitting it should display the error message.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it's more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is clearly a code review related question. Funny how people think this question shows any kind of research effort.

Answer (score 1):

`.validate()` function of jquery validation is applied for form id not for table id.
You are given `.validate()` to table id

Answer (score 0):

The validate plugin requires ID of the form to be validated unlike the id of the table you are using now `tbl-employee`. Wrap your HTML inside a form and the id of this form to validate.

```
$("#id_of_your_form").validate({..
```

Also, you are not having `required` attribute for the input textbox. Add it to the desired textboxes and the validations will work.

Eg. `<input type="text" id="txt-name" required/>`

Comment: I want in Jquery Validation Only

Comment: For the validations to work, you need to mark input text fields as `required`, otherwise it won't show error.